# ¿Qué función puedo usar para averiguar si los caracteres de un string son números decimales?

Tags: python

Holaa owo, les explico, la función `isdigit()` comprueba si todos los caracteres del texto son números:

```
print("123".isdigit())
```

Esto da como salida: `True`. Ya que si, todo en ese string son números; el problema está con que si lo haces con un número decimal da `False`, ya que el punto decimal no es un número:

```
print("1.23".isdigit())
```

¿Qué otra función a código puedo usar? Saluditos uwu

Comment: Creo que un `try/except` serviría

Comment: pone la cadena a considerar y la sintaxis que usaste

Comment: Podrías aclarar y ahondar más en tu pregunta ¿por favor? "si un número decimal lo considera un dígito". Un dígito es simplemente un símbolo (del sistema decimal), y un número está compuesto de dígitos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

una forma sería:

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
string = "4"

try:
    if str(float(string)) == string:
        print("es decimal")
    else:
        print("no es decimal")
        
except:
    print("no es ni un número")
```

en donde si se logra la conversión a decimal se la vuelve a cadena y se compara con la original, si son iguales, lo era.

Comment: solo un pequeño detalle, en caso se ponga `.2` (Python igual lo interpreta como decimal), la condición no se cumplirá

Comment: es cierto me olvide que algunos lo escriben así

Comment: Muchassss gracias por las respuestas, después de verlas me sentí tonto xd, muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo :3

Comment: Prueba con +3.14

Comment: Prueba con 1_000_000

Comment: ya veo, seguramente el usuario lo escribiría como las representaciones de python en lugar de la forma convencional, salvo claro está el delimitador.

Answer (score 3):

Una forma de saber si un *string* que contiene un numero es decimal es usando la clausula `try/except`

```py
string = "2.2"

try:
    if not string.isdecimal(): #verificamos que no sea entero
        number = float(string)
        print(number)
    else:
        print("no es decimal")
except:
    print("no es decimal")
```

Otra forma de verificar si es decimal, podría ser comprobando que tenga el punto `.`

```py
string = "2.2"

#verificamos que tenga el punto y que el resto no sea letras
if '.' in string and  not string.replace(".","").isalpha():
    print("es decimal")
else:
    print("no es decimal")
```

Esto no es muy recomendado pues en caso el *string* sea `2.2.2` o `.` igual se cumplirá la condición, por lo que la forma mas sencilla y segura de verificarlo es con un `try/except`, en caso la conversión falle significara que no es un decimal.

**Nota**: Nosotros llamamos decimal a un numero que tiene una parte entera y una decimal `1,2` pero Python no reconoce el tipo de dato *decimal*, en su lugar es `float`, tampoco reconoce la coma `,` como separador decimal, en su lugar usa el punto `.`

Comment: @tincopasan edite la respuesta, creo que ya no habrá errores, en el segundo caso dije, que no seria recomendado ya que habrá errores, y eso es uno de los errores

Comment: claro, la respuesta actual es 100% funcional pero quien no vio tu primer respuesta deja a mi comentario como equivocado, en fin.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma alternativa que podrías usar es probar si la cadena se puede transformar en flotante. Si la transformación ocurre con exito, hacemos que la función devuelva True. Si ocurre un ValueError (tipo de error que ocurre cuando falla la transformación) hacemos que la función devuelva False.

```
def isfloat(numero):
    try:
        float(numero)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

# Aquí probé con las diversas propuestas que se hicieron en los comentarios de otras respuestas, más algunas propuestas mias.
print(".2", isfloat(".2"))
print("+3.14", isfloat("+3.14"))
print("-3.14", isfloat("-3.14"))
print("1_000_000", isfloat("1_000_000"))
print("3.14", isfloat("3.14"))
print("3", isfloat("3")) # Mi función considera a los enteros como flotantes. Si no deseas esto, dimelo en los comentarios.
print("hola.mundo", isfloat("hola.mundo"))
```

Comment: Viendo tu respuesta, las otras y los comentarios, se plantea: averiguar si los caracteres de una cadena son un número decimal, no que los convierta a decimal, ¿qué tienen de decimal las cadenas: "-3.14","1_000_000", "3"? se pueden convertir a decimal no quiere decir que la cadena como tal lo sea,

Comment: @tincopasan Espero la respuesta de OP para saber eso. Se puede encontrar una forma de saber si SON decimales y no enteros. Como una condición que indique si hay un punto en la cadena. "-3.14" es decimal, de eso estoy muy seguro. "1_000_000" tiene una notación de python y es entero. El 3 es un entero. Mi duda, la cual espero que OP responda, es si mi función debe de devolver True si el numero es entero.